# Format help: Last Variable not coming up as it should

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have written a code that send an email out to someone. They have asked for the data to be printed on the screen as well whenever the code is run. I used the `Write-Host` cmdlet as below.

```
Write-Host "server: $serverName `t ipaddress: $ipAddressValue `t process: $processName `t status: $statusString"
```

the data comes up on PowerShell, all in a straight line as it should apart from the last variable `$statusstring`,  the status results come up in different lines and isn't in the same order the other 3 variables.

- process: TestTrack Server   status: Running
- process: eventlog     status: Running
- process: WMSVC    status: Stopped
- process: TFSJobAgent      status:       Running
- process: Dhcp     status: Running
- process UI0Detect           status: Stopped

Any ideas how I can get the status to be all in a straight line as well?

Comment: Can you do `$statusString.GetType().Name`?

Comment: That didnt do anything but i have just come across something. If i move status: $statusString" before any other variable its all fine so im not sure if its something to do with the variable statusString itself

Comment: $statusString = $statusString.Remove(0,"@{Status=".Length)
            $statusString = $statusString.Remove($statusString.IndexOf("}"))

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want tabular output. Why not create objects and use proper formatting cmdlets?

```
$props = [ordered]@{
  server    = $serverName
  ipaddress = $ipAddressValue
  process   = $processName
  status    = $statusString.Trim()
}
$o = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $props
```

From the object (or list of objects) you can create string output like this:

```
$o | Format-Table | Out-String
```

or HTML output like this:

```
$o | ConvertTo-Html
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option: Stop using `Write-Host`. You cannot contorl the output to all show up on one line using that cmdlet. Your better off in making a custom PSObject to build the output, and then just pass that to `Format-Table`.